# Downloading osm data in geospatial format

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis, overpass-api

I am trying to download osm data from this relation for a waterway. https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3396950#map=10/13.0280/75.8894

The option to download XML is available, and I have used QuickOSM plugin in QGIS, and used Overpass Turbo interface to download in a geospatial format but in vain.

Is there a way to download osm data based on the relation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Overpass Turbo allows you to export the results of Overpass queries as geojson files that you can open in QGIS or ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro. By default, the query returns XML data, but the toolbar in the upper left of Overpass Turbo has an *Export* option that allows for geojson downloads.

Here is the proper Overpass query: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/149i. Since you're only interested in one relation, it's pretty straightforward--just query by OSM ID. More information on query syntax is available in the [Overpass Query Language docs](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#out).